# Android .NET: A Binding must be configured for this channel factory

Tags: android, web-services, wcf, xamarin, basichttpbinding

**I have received the following error when trying to call a method from my WCF Web Service application in my Xamarin Android Application: System.InvalidOperationException: A Binding must be configured for this channel factory.**

I searched the internet for any solutions but I was unlucky.

My server side is created in a WCF Web Service application in Visual Studio 2013 for Web.
My client side is an Android Application created in Xamarin Studio.

Calling the methods from the server works fine in WebForms as well as WinForms, but it is not working with Xamarin.AndroidApplications.

I found this link but It was'nt enaugh :( : **http://www.nullskull.com/a/10476775/xamarin-cross-platform-application-consuming-wcf--part-1.aspx**

If someone could help me I will be very thankful!

Comment: Did you create the binding and pass it to the client constructor?

Comment: I have done the following: run the web service and then I copy the URL... in Xamarin Studio in my solution my project---> add web reference and I inserted the previous URL. And that is it

Comment: I did not need other binding types in WinForms or WebForms...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/